# hide a table when rendering a PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, html

I hope someone can help me.

This my code basically I am creating a quote PDF. In this case when there is no training products the table should be rendered in the PDF. And I am able to hide every single line with this logic rendered="{!HWLineItems.size>0}". But the issue is that in the header remain a blank line with the table format (background colour number of columns). How can I remove that format? I tried with outputpannel but then is removing the format but unfortunately is also removing the format when the query is not empty.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

```
        <apex:page standardController="Quote" action="{!populatePriceOnQuote}" extensions="QuotePDFController" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false"  renderAs="pdf">

            <head>
            <style type="text/css" >

            @page { 
                size: letter portrait;

                margin-left: 2cm;
                margin-right: 2cm;
                margin-top: 4cm;
                margin-bottom: 2cm;
                font-family: 'SansSerif';
                @top-left {
                    content: element(header_left);
                }

                @top-center {
                    content: element(header_center);
                }

                @top-right {
                    content: element(header_right);
                }

                @bottom-left {
                    content: element(footer_left);
                }

                @bottom-center {
                    content: element(footer_center);
                }

                @bottom-right {
                    content: counter(page) " ("  counter(pages) ")";
                }
            }


        .header_left {
            position: running(header_left);
            margin-bottom:10px;
            color: #A0A0A0;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-family: 'SansSerif';

        }



        .header_center{
            position: running(header_center);
            font-family: 'SansSerif';
        }

        .header_right {
            text-align: right;
            position: running(header_right);
            font-family: 'SansSerif';
        }

        .rayHeader1 {
            font-size: 13pt;
            color: #365F91;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: 'SansSerif';
        }

        .rayHeader2 {
            font-size: 10pt;
            color: #365F91;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: 'SansSerif';
        }

        .rayBody {
            font-size: 10pt;
            page-break-after: always;
            font-family: 'SansSerif';
        }

        .rayBody2 {
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-family: 'SansSerif';
        }

        #quotePricing {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;

        }

        #quotePricing td, #quotePricing th {
            font-size: 1em;
            border: 1px solid #4F81BD;
            p
            ing: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
        }

        #quotePricing th {
            font-size: 1.1em;
            text-align: left;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 4px;
            background-color: #4F81BD;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        #quotePricing tr.alt td {
            color: #000000;
            background-color: #DBE5F1;
        }


        .footer_left {
            text-align: left;
            position: running(footer_left);
        }

        .footer_center {
            text-align: center;
            position: running(footer_center);
        }

        .footer_right {
            text-align: right;
            font-family: 'SansSerif';
            position: running(footer_right);
        }

        .pageNumber:before {
            content: counter(page); 
        }

        .pageCount:before {
            content: counter(pages);  
        }

        .rayTD1 {

            color: #005380;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 2px;

        }




        .rayTerms {

            color: #365F91;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .rayTable {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .rayTable td {
            font-size: 1em;
            border: 0.5px solid #4F81BD;
            padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
        }




        </style>
        </head> 

    <table id="quotePricing">
<!--<apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>-->
   <thead  >
       <th width="12%" ><apex:outputText rendered="{!TrainingLineItems.size>0}">Qty</apex:outputText></th>
       <th ><apex:outputText rendered="{!TrainingLineItems.size>0}">Application/Product</apex:outputText></th>
       <th  ><apex:outputText rendered="{!TrainingLineItems.size>0}">Comment</apex:outputText></th>
   </thead>
<apex:repeat value="{!TrainingLineItems}" var="line">
<apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!TrainingLineItems.size>0}">
   <tr class="alt">
    <td width="12%"><apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0}" rendered="{!TrainingLineItems.size>0}"><apex:param value="{!line.Quantity}" /></apex:outputText></td>
     <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.Prod_Name__c}" rendered="{!TrainingLineItems.size>0}"></apex:OutputField></td>  
     <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.Description}" rendered="{!TrainingLineItems.size>0}"></apex:OutputField></td>
  </tr>
  <!--<apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>-->
  </apex:variable>
</apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways of handling this, both involve modifying your controller to detect when the wrapper list of is zero length. One is to wrap the wrapper in a 2nd wrapper that contains a variable with a boolean value of whether the `inner wrapper` is greater than zero. If false, then the outer wrapper uses a repeat located outside the table to tell the `table` not to render at all (`render = false`). If true, it tells it to render (`render = true`).

An even simpler method is to simply use another Boolean variable that's assigned to the Boolean I just mentioned. Then wrap the entire table in a `Div` tag. Use the value of the Boolean to set `render=true` or `render=false` for the `Div`. That way, either the table renders or it doesn't. No need to process the wrapper at all if it has no records.